# Go: How to check precision loss when converting float64 to float32

Tags: go, floating-point, precision

I have a scenario where I receive a float64 value, but must send it down the wire to another service as a float32 value. We know the received value should always fit into a float32. However, to be safe I want to log the case where we are losing data by converting to float32.

**This code block does not compile**, since you can't compare float32 to float64 directly.

```
func convert(input float64) (output float32, err error) {
    const tolerance = 0.001
    output = float32(input)
    if output > input+tolerance || output < input-tolerance {
        return 0, errors.New("lost too much precision")
    }
    return output, nil
}
```

**Is there an easy way to check that I am hitting this condition?** This check will happen at high frequency, so I want to avoid doing string conversions.

Comment: What do you mean by “the received value should always fit into a float32”? Does that mean the received value is always representable in a `float32` (exactly, with no rounding error at all)? Or that the received value is always within the finite range of a `float32` but might not be representable in a `float32` (will change slightly when converted to `float32`)? Or something else? If it does not mean the value is representable, how much error is acceptable?

Comment: With that statement I meant that we know the values will not be greater than the max float32 value (3.4e38). I am also hoping that the float32 value is not more than 0.001 off of the float64 value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert back the `float32` value to `float64`, just for the validation.

To check if the converted value represents the same value, simply compare it to the original value (the input). It's also enough / idiomatic to just return an `ok bool` info (instead of an `error`):

```
func convert(input float64) (output float32, ok bool) {
    output = float32(input)
    ok = float64(output) == input
    return
}
```

(Note: edge cases like `NaN` are not checked.)

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(convert(1))
fmt.Println(convert(1.5))
fmt.Println(convert(0.123456789))
fmt.Println(convert(math.MaxFloat32))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ggRF228UsP7)):

```
1 true
1.5 true
0.12345679 false
3.4028235e+38 true
```

Note that this will often give `ok = false` result because the precision of `float32` is less than that of `float64`, even though the converted value may be very close to the input.

So in practice it would be more useful to check the difference of the converted value. Your proposed solution checks for the absolute difference value which is not so useful: for example `1000000.1` and `1000000` are very close numbers, even though the difference is `0.1`. `0.0001` and `0.00011` have much less difference: `0.00001`, yet the difference compared to the numbers is much bigger.

So you should check the relative difference, for example:

```
func convert(input float64) (output float32, ok bool) {
    const maxRelDiff = 1e-8

    output = float32(input)
    diff := math.Abs(float64(output) - input)
    ok = diff <= math.Abs(input)*maxRelDiff

    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(convert(1))
fmt.Println(convert(1.5))
fmt.Println(convert(1e20))
fmt.Println(convert(math.Pi))
fmt.Println(convert(0.123456789))
fmt.Println(convert(math.MaxFloat32))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nsa_cpu_8UY)):

```
1 true
1.5 true
1e+20 false
3.1415927 false
0.12345679 false
3.4028235e+38 true
```

Comment: Small `double` values like `math.SmallestNonzeroFloat32 * 1.5` remain troublesome.  Unclear what OP wants in those cases.  A possible alternative is to switch to absolute error when `float` is sub-normal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Check that the value does not exceed the upper or lower value limit.  Then ensure the 52 - 23 least significant bits are 0. (in a nutshell)

Comment: This fails to detect rounding errors in the conversion of numbers that are subnormal in `float32`. Consider 0x1.55555p-140. This is above the smallest representable non-zero number, 0x1p-149, and the low 29 bits of the `float64` significand are zeros, but it is not representable in `float32`.